# Retracting an oath

Tags: quran, hadith, sin, oaths

I made an oath to Allah, saying that I swear by Him to abstain from a particular thing for a certain period of time, I managed to for a few days but I have now realised that I cannot keep up for the remaining time, can I retract this oath and then it becomes rendered null and void?

Answer (score 1):

you want to break your promise  and break your oath! You must atone for this quit. This is a penalty for the bad promise man who breaks his oath.
The prescribed punishment for breaking an oath is the release of a slave or the feeding of ten poor people or the covering of ten poor people and, if incapacitated, the fasting for three consecutive days.